# Accessing MongoDB from AppEngine app

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine

I have an app, written in Golang which works with MongoDB. I also have running VM instance of MongoDB, deployed with Click-to-deploy.

I can connect to external MongoDB instance, the app works locally, and on VM Instance on GAE, but **NOT** when started as appengine instance (i.e. via goapp deploy). In logs I see 'no reachable servers' error. I've double tested all network configuration and opened MongoDB port in my 'default' network.

I found some articles and posts that say you can't use MongoDB with appengine, and need to go with Datastore, but they all are quite old (like 2011/2012) and I can't find confirmation in AppEngine docs.

So the questions are:

- can I use GAE-hosted MongoDB with my AppEngine application?
- if yes, how can I debug this connectivity issue with appengine instances?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GAE outgoing is limited. you can't connect to arbitrary resources. That has not changed much lately. If you can make MongoDB talk over a HTTP interface you can use that.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Collingwood, but how can I be 100% sure? I can't find restrictions description in docs.

Comment: It's more about what you are allowed to do then what you are not allowed. Assume everything is disallowed and only what is documented is allowed. Connect to arbitrary resources/ports? You'll need to use the managed instances instead where you can run any code and use any connection method. See here for that: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/ Whereas GAE comes with it's own DB (NOSQL/SQL) that it want's you to use, hence your current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can't use direct MongoDB connection from appengine app due to the restricted nature of appengine sandbox.
From https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/:
**Network Access: Only via App Engine services (includes outbound sockets)**

There are some possbilities to access MongoDB via HTTP REST interface, but it's not my case.

Comment: This still doest not changed ? I am struggling to connect MongoDB running on mongolab ( on google cloud platform ) with my Lumen project running on Google App Engine. I should quit trying ? no chance i can connect it ?