# Integrate Google App Engine and Compute MongoDB, possible?

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I've spent the last few weeks really climbing all around the Google App Engine (GAE) and Google Compute Engine (GCE), so I feel that I have a decent understanding about the two related but different platforms. But I'm stuck and want to make sure I jump in the right direction to move forward.

I'm creating a small private business website with a limited number of customers.  We are talking 20 concurrent users.

So this question may be more architectural than technical.

I wanted to try and use the MongoDB because of the flexibility of the schema, so here is where I'm stuck.

My initial attempt was to connect via the following:

**Option 1:**

- GAE (Java) --> MongoDB Java Driver --> GCE (MongoDB)
- This is a complete failure because the GAE sandbox will not allow this.

**Option 2:**

- GAE (Java) --> RESTFul MongoDB Call --> GCE (MongoDB / Restful front end)
- I have not fully explored this yet, but this appears promising, but I really don't want to use RESTful to connect to my DB

Which leaves me with where I'm heading.

**Option 3:**

- GCE (Java/Tomcat) --> MongoDB driver --> GCE (MongoDB)
- Ditch GAE and go full in GCE :|

I'd love some feedback. Here are the other stackoverflow answers that I referenced heavily when researching this issue:

- Old question, but a few of the responses are newer and useful,
  specifically from user @eloone, but still not clear, how the plumbing
  would work

  - [Any one tried MongoDB on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263395/any-one-tried-mongodb-on-google-app-engine)
- Both below say basically the same thing, which is "NO", so
  that pushed me to Option #2 or Option #3

  - [google app engine and mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216069/google-app-engine-and-mongodb)
  - [Accessing MongoDB from AppEngine app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089343/accessing-mongodb-from-appengine-app)

### My specific questions:

- Since I don't have to scale, do I really need GAE? (just trying to be fast... and lazy :D)
- What am I giving up by abandoning GAE? I was using it because it seemed easy and quick, (as long as you use mysql)

Needless to say, this is my first question ever on stackoverflow, which I read about every day, so be nice if this question seems out of line.  I figured if I was struggling, probably many others were as well.  :D

---

**Answer Summary:**
3 perfectly good answers were put forward:

1. User Google Datastore (I had misunderstood what this was)
2. User the new(ish) Java Managed VMs
3. Just use GCE VM and do what I want.

I researched all of these, and decided that for me #1 was the best option for the moment because it was the path of least resistance, but I'm leaving the door wide open to shifting to #2 or #3 in the future if the need arises.

Thanks everybody.  I'll mark the response about using GCE as the accepted answer because it does answer the question even though I went in a different direction.

Comment: why not just use the datastore?

Comment: I was under the impression ( incorrectly ?) that the datastore only connected to Google's provided mysql database. Am I misunderstanding that pieces of this platform? (opening google....)

Comment: Datastore is Google's proprietary database that can be used out of the box in GAE, nothing to do with mySQL or mongoDB.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

Comment: I think your option 1 should be possible with a [Java Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/) but you should also look into [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) as it is schemaless.

Comment: I believe that GAE has recently added support for socket comm (as well as HTTP), so I"m surprised to hear that MongoDB drivers/client library still doesn't work on GAE.  Anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you don't need GAE even if you have to scale

- you can use [autoscaler in GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/)  so you can be lazy and fast with GCE
- by  [installing MongoDB with a click](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mongodb/)
- GCE plays nice with MongoDB especially if you want to replicate becouse of the very fast connections between datacenters.

Comment: I will also add that Managed VMs will let you use the App Engine runtime on a GCE instance, if you want: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/

Comment: I'm leaning this weay, but I have a question, and probably a newbie question, but if I'm going to use a Compute VM as the webserver, do I just do the manual setup using sudo apt-get tomcat7 apache2 and wire together like good old times and open the 80/443 on the firewall?